# Set column name for multiple select count (*) tables

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I set a column name for the output from bellow query ?

```
select 
(select count(*) from t_table1 id = 1)
+
(select count(*) from t_table2 id = 1)
+
(select count(*) from t_table3 id = 1)
```

Comment: You should take a look at `union` and `union all` in sql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `as`:

```
select ( (select count(*) from t_table1 where id = 1) +
         (select count(*) from t_table2 where id = 1) +
         (select count(*) from t_table3 where id = 1)
       ) as col
```

Notice that I put the entire expression in parentheses.  This is not required, but it makes the code more readable.  I also fixed the subqueries.

If you want to run this multiple times, then a correlated subquery makes it easier to manage the ids:

```
select ( (select count(*) from t_table1 t where t.id = x.id) +
         (select count(*) from t_table2 t where t.id = x.id) +
         (select count(*) from t_table3 t where t.id = x.id)
       ) as col
from (select 1 as id) x;
```

Then, to modify the query, you only need to change the value in one place.

Answer (score 0):

use **as** Keyword

```
select (select count(*) from t_table1 id = 1)+
(select count(*) from t_table2 id = 1)+
(select count(*) from t_table3 id = 1) as result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(count_tab) as col_name from(
(select count(*) as count_tab from t_table1 id = 1)
union all
(select count(*) from t_table2 id = 1)
union all
(select count(*) from t_table3 id = 1))
```